# Session clears on app restart in hapi-auth-cookie

Tags: node.js, heroku, hapi.js

I am using hapi-auth-cookie for cookie base session and authentication. But whenever app is restarted the session clears out. 
And on heroku its clearing frequently without restart.

Please suggest the fix.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku has an ephemeral file system, because every dyno is an independent container which doesn't share it's file system with any other.

That means every time your app is restarted (when you deploy it or once every 24 hours), your file system is reset. It is also not shared accross dynos.

For this reason, you need your sessions to store their data in an hosted database, like redis and not the file system.

Doing so should fix your problem.